# Posting json data using c# Httprequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, httprequest, c#-2.0

Iam trying to post json data to a URL. My Request data structure is

Method Name : PAYTYPE

```
{ id: "string",uid: "string", pwd: "string", apiKey: "string",paymentCategory: int, paymentType: int }
```

i need to send a Header Named SIGNATURE along with this data and the value of the signature is the Encrypted Request data.But i dont know how to add header(SIGNATURE)  and method name(PAYTYPE) and the Value(Encrypted data) for posting.
I have done something like this

```
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("PAYTYPE", "SIGNATURE"+sEncrypteddata)
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = "{\"id\":\"2423432432\"," +
                      "\"uid\":\"id123\","+
                      "\"pwd\":\"pass\","+
                      "\"apiKey\":\"2423432432\","+
                      "\"paymentCategory\":0"+
                       "\"paymentType\":0}";

        streamWriter.Write(json);
        streamWriter.Flush();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    HttpWebResponse  httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Iam getting Exception as "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."

if the code structure is Ok then i want to know how to add Header ,signature and value to this or is there any other steps.

Comment: "Method not allowed" sounds like the server expects a GET request rather than a POST request? If you google it, there are also other reasons to get that response, one of which may be relevant to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line before adding the custom header:

```
httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```